# Ionic 3 truncate a text inside a for loop of an array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, truncate, truncation

I had a api response from a **server** that contains one property that has a long text. I would like to truncate them properly in a simple way and I used this [package](https://github.com/yellowspot/ng2-truncate).

This is my code inside my **html**

```
<ion-card class="pin" *ngFor="let item of winner">
        <div class="wrapper" (tap)="onView(item)">
          <img [src]="item?.image | image:'300'" class="img" />
        </div>
        <button ion-button clear icon-only item-start class="profile">
          <ion-avatar item-start>
            <img [src]="" height="30" class="img-avatar" onError="this.src='https://vollrath.com/ClientCss/images/VollrathImages/No_Image_Available.jpg';">
          </ion-avatar>
          <ion-card-title ion-text color="textBlack"> {{item?.name?.firstName}} {{item?.name?.lastName}}
          </ion-card-title>
        </button>
        <p class="card-subtitle" *ngIf="item?.comment?.length >= 100" text-wrap>{{item?.comment | truncate : 100}}</p>

        <button ion-button full small block *ngIf="truncating && item.comment.length > 100" (tap)="truncating = false">
          Read More
        </button>
        <button ion-button full small block *ngIf="!truncating && item.comment.length > 100" (tap)="truncating = true">
            Show Less
        </button>
      </ion-card>
```

In my **ts file**

```
import { TruncateModule } from '@yellowspot/ng-truncate';

truncating = true;
```

I don't have any errors here but the truncating is working but on all elements of the array.

How do I trigger and truncate for the `comment` for the specific **item** in my array?

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo could extend your Model and store that `truncating` in your Model instead of your Component.

I suspect your Model is called `winner`:

```
export class winner{
//your fields
truncating: boolean;
}
```

and change your buttons to something like this

```
<button ion-button full small block *ngIf="item.truncating && item.comment.length > 100" (tap)="item.truncating = false">
Read More
</button>
<button ion-button full small block *ngIf="!item.truncating && item.comment.length > 100" (tap)="item.truncating = true">
Show Less
</button>
```

Comment: When I got the response I mapped the array and inserted the new value. Thank you!

Comment: glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this HTML code.

```
  <p class="card-subtitle" *ngIf="truncating" text-wrap>{{item?.comment | truncate : 100}}</p>
  <p class="card-subtitle" *ngIf="!truncating" text-wrap>{{item?.comment}}</p>
```